# Problem in creating thumbnails in android application

Tags: android

I am working on a file manager kind of application in android in which i want to create thumbnails of the images.Thumbnails are getting created but the application often force closes giving out Out Of Memory Exception...

i tried out following code

```
icon.setImageURI(Uri.parse(path));
                icon.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);
                icon.setLayoutParams(new     LinearLayout.LayoutParams(30,30));
```

addView(icon);

Comment: Can you post the current code that is causing the crash?  Have you tried create scaled bitmaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that when you load the images you specify a sample rate to [BitmapFactory.Options](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html). This will keep your bitmaps from getting too big:

```
BitmapFactory.Options opts = new BitmapFactory.Options();
opts.inSampleSize = 4;
 ... use a BitmapFactory method, passing opts ...
```

Comment: But how should i pass image URI using BitmapFactory?

Comment: Check out the BitmapFactory methods. You can pass it a file, an input stream, ...

Answer (score 0):

I did like this it worked

```
Bitmap imagethumbnail=BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);  //complete file path
imagethumbnail=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(imagethumbnail, 40, 40, true);
```